# MySQL Database - Transferring inputted data to a text file (PHP, HTML, SQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I just can't seem to figure out the logic to write the inputted information (contact form) to a text file within the localhost.

I am uploading all of this information on my school's server. If I please could get some help. Truly can't figure this part out.

> HTML CODE:

```
    <form action="Registered.php" method="post">
     <p>
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input name="fName" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input name="lName" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Address:</label>
        <input name="address" type="text">        
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>State:</label>
        <select name="statedropdown">
<option value="Al"> Al </option>
<option value="AK"> AK </option>
<option value="AS">AS</option>
<option value="AR">AR</option>
<option value="CA">CA</option>
<option value="CO">CO</option>
<option value="CT">CT</option>
<option value="DE">DE</option>
<option value="DC">DC</option>
<option value="FL">FL</option>
<option value="GA">GA</option>
<option value="HI">HI</option>
<option value="ID">ID</option>
<option value="IL">IL</option>
<option value="IN">IN</option>
<option value="IA">IA</option>
<option value="KS">KS</option>
<option value="KY">KY</option>
<option value="LA">LA</option>
<option value="ME">ME</option>
<option value="MD">MD</option>
<option value="MA">MA</option>
<option value="MI">MI</option>
<option value="MN">MN</option>
<option value="MS">MS</option>
<option value="MO">MO</option>
<option value="MT">MT</option>
<option value="NE">NE</option>
<option value="NV">NV</option>
<option value="NH">NH</option>
<option value="NJ">NJ</option>
<option value="NM">NM</option>
<option value="NY">NY</option>
<option value="NC">NC</option>
<option value="ND">ND</option>
<option value="OH">OH</option>
<option value="OK">OK</option>
<option value="OR">OR</option>
<option value="PA">PA</option>
<option value="RI">RI</option>
<option value="SC">SC</option>
<option value="SD">SD</option>
<option value="TN">TN</option>
<option value="UT">UT</option>
<option value="VT">VT</option>
<option value="VA">VA</option>
<option value="WA">WA</option>
<option value="WV">WV</option>
<option value="WI">WI</option>
<option value="WY">WY</option>
</select>       
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>ZIP Code:</label>
        <input name="zip" required="required" placeholder="12345" type="text">        
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input name="email" required="required" placeholder="fake@email.com" type="email">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Phone Number:</label>
        <input name="phone" required="required" placeholder="912-555-1234" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input value="Submit" type="submit">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </p>
    <p>
        <td align="center"><a href="http://web-students.armstrong.edu/~tp2283/FormData.txt"> View contacts in database </a></td>
    </p>
    <p>
        <td align="center"><a href="http://web-students.armstrong.edu/~tp2283/contactsFile.htm"> View contacts in file </a></td>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

> PHP CODE:

```
    <html>    
   <head>
      <title> Thank You </title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php
            $username="YYYYYYYY";
            $password="XXXXXXXX";
            $database="ZZZZZZZZ";

                #declare variables
                $fName = $_POST['fName'];
                $lName = $_POST['lName'];
                $address = $_POST['address'];
                $statedropdown = $_POST['statedropdown'];
                $zip = $_POST['zip'];
                $phone = $_POST['phone'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

                mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
                mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
                $query = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

                mysql_close();
?>
      <h1 align = "center"> Thanks for Registering! </h1> <br /><br />
         <p align = "center"> Your information is: </p>
            <table align = "center">
               <tr>
                  <td> First Name: </td>
                  <td> &nbsp </td> 
                  <td> <?php echo $fName ?> </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td> Last Name: </td>
                  <td> &nbsp </td> 
                  <td> <?php echo $lName ?> </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td> Address: </td>
                  <td> &nbsp </td> 
                  <td> <?php echo $address ?> </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td> State: </td>
                  <td> &nbsp </td> 
                  <td> <?php echo $statedropdown ?> </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td> Zip: </td>
                  <td> &nbsp </td> 
                  <td> <?php echo $zip ?> </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td> Telephone: </td>
                  <td> &nbsp </td> 
                  <td> <?php echo $phone ?> </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td> E-mail: </td>
                  <td> &nbsp </td> 
                  <td> <?php echo $email ?> </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

<?php
    if($_POST['saveToFile'] == 'Save to File') {
        $outputstring =
        "First Name: $fName
        Last Name: $lName
        Address: $address
        State: $statedropdown
        Zip: $zip
        Telephone: $phone
        Email: $email
        -----------------------\n";

        $fp = fopen("FormData.txt", 'a');
        flock($fp, LOCK_EX);

        fwrite($fp, $outputstring, strlen($outputstring));
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>
      <p align="center"><a href="Assignment3.html"> Return to Main Page </a> </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

If someone could please help me out this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: try creating the file manually first

Answer (score 1):

Where do you get the variable `$_POST['saveToFile']` from? Shouldn't there be something like a checkbox in the form?

Are there any error messages?

I would go like this:

```
$outputstring =
    . "First Name: $fName \n"
    . "Last Name: $lName \n"
    . "Address: $address \n"
    . "State: $statedropdown \n"
    . "Zip: $zip \n"
    . "Telephone: $phone \n"
    . "Email: $email \n"
    . "-----------------------\n";

file_put_contents("FormData.txt", $outputstring, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

The function file_put_contents opens and locks the file, appends the data to it, unlocks and finally closes it. So the only difference is the better overview.

Comment: That worked amazing!! Thank you so much! One more question you might be able to help me solve

I need to write an SQL script that when ran, generates and populates the appropriate tables with at least 100 contacts.

Comment: You're welcome. You can ask a new question for that. But you should give more details like from where the contacts should be populated and if it should be a PHP script executing a SQL query and so on.